# Constructing a Klein Bottle

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Let $a>b>0$, $f: \mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb C^2 \cong\mathbb R^4$, $$f(x,y)=(g^2(x,y), g(x,y)h(y))$$ where $g(x,y)=(a+b \cos y)e^{ix}$ and $h(y)=\sin y + \sin 2y$.

Use $f$ to construct a Klein Bottle into $\mathbb R^4$.

In this differential manifolds text it gives the original Klein Bottle as starting with an infinite cylinder $E=\mathbb R \times S^1$ and consider the action of $(\mathbb Z, +)$ on $E$ by $$\phi(n, (x, (\cos t, \sin t)))=(x+n, (\cos t, (-1)^n \sin t)).$$
I have a basic understanding of manifolds and converting their mappings, but I've never converted two algebraic equations, let alone trigonometric ones, from one mapping to another.

Comment: So how does $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ act on $\Bbb R^2$ so that $f$ is invariant under that action?

Comment: IIRC, is $h(y) = \sin t + i\sin(2t)$ (the second summand is imaginary)...?

Comment: Andrew, there was no "i" in the h(y) equation.

Comment: Dr. Shifrin, would (x,y) elements of V being a vector space of manifold M on $\mathbb R^2$ with M being a compact smooth manifold hold f invariant?